# Ubunu won't load

Tags: boot, apt, dpkg

i'm a newbie and i don't know what i did wrong but my ubuntu 20.10 won't load anymore i get the following message when i want to boot in ubuntu:

```
/dev/nme0n1p1: clean, 1103073/61054976 files
[ 3,496619] EDAC skx: ECC is disabled on imc 0
[ 3,5648030] EDAC skx: ECC is disabled on imc 0
```

...

After this message nothing happens

I was trying to install a package which didn't work. I tried to to find what the problem was and these statements are one of the last i typed in the terminal (which honestly i don't know what they do but i found them on the internet to try to get the package installed)

```
sudo apt-get -o Debug::pkgProblemsolver=yes dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get remove --dry-run package-name
sudo dpkg--configure -a
sudo apt-get clean & sudo-apt get update
```

I've already booted into the recovery mode and tried all the different options, but it still stuck with the error message when trying to boot normally.

Is there something else i can try?

Comment: You didn't google, did you? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63383981/error-edac-skx-ecc-is-disabled-on-imc-0-on-ubuntu-20-04) someone asked and received a solution. And make sure you are running Ubuntu on X11 **NOT** on wayland

Comment: Actuall, I have the same problem and the solution provided on stackoverflow page you cited did not help at all. I would also be interested if someone else has a different solution.